# Amazon book flipping CSS animation: how is it coded?

Tags: html, css, transform

[Link to example. Hover over the book on the left side](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1476772576)

As you can see, the book seems to open towards the user.
I already have the first part of the animation: [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/q1f9tmpf/)

HTML:

```
<h1>Boek opendoen animatie</h1>

<div class="achtergrond">
        <img class="foto" src="http://i.imgur.com/u19t6iW.jpg" alt="Cover">
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
div.achtergrond {
    background-color: black;
    width: 250px;
    height: 376px;

}
img.foto {
    width: 250px;
    height: auto;

    -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 1s; /* For Safari 3.1 to 6.0 */
/*    -webkit-transform-origin: 0 0;*/
}

img.foto:hover {
/*    -webkit-transform: scaleX(1.5)*/
    -webkit-transform: matrix3d(0.8660254, 0, 0.5, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, -0.5, 0, 0.8660254, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1);
}
```

Now this doesn't seem to enlarge the right corners of the book, so it doesn't seem like the cover is coming towards the user.

I've tried -webkit-perspective, transform-style,... but can't seem to get the desired effect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found how I need to fix this. 
I tried the perspective and perspective-origin options before but didn't put them in the correct place. 
These options have to be put in the parent element (here the "achtergrond"-div).

See [w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_perspective-origin.asp) with the quote

> When defining the perspective-origin property for an element, it is the CHILD elements that are positioned, NOT the element itself.

The new CSS is thus:

```
div.achtergrond {
    background-color: black;
    width: 250px;
    height: 376px;
    -webkit-perspective: 250px; /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
    -webkit-perspective-origin: 100% 30%; /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */

}
img.foto {
    width: 250px;
    height: auto;
    -webkit-transform-origin: 0 0;
    -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
    -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 1s; /* For Safari 3.1 to 6.0 */

}

img.foto:hover {
/*    -webkit-transform: scaleX(1.5)*/
    transform: rotateY(-20deg); 
-moz-transform: rotateY(-20deg);
-webkit-transform: rotateY(-20deg);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

try this css on image hover

```
transform: rotateY(-20deg); 
-moz-transform: rotateY(-20deg);
-webkit-transform: rotateY(-20deg);
```

Comment: The matrix3d I have is equal to rotateY(-30deg), so this doesn't make a difference in output.

Comment: Thanks for the help but I've come up with my own solution (see my answer). In your fiddle there's no use of the perspective option so you still don't see the page coming towards you.